# Android app crashing on HTC 4g

Tags: android, crash

I have an android app that is crashing only on HTC 4g , tried on various other phones , but that is working fine. Since 4g is not available on my side (this has been told to me by one of my client) and I cant test it on HTC 4g, how can I remove this crash.

Can 4g thing or just HTC model can have a reason for this crash??

How can I get a crash log from his phone (he is not at my location) . Is there any way he can send me the crash log??

What could be the reason for the crash ? HTC or 4g??

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues when send my build to my clients so I integrated ACRA in my project, Its simple and easy to use

http://code.google.com/p/acra/

> What is ACRA ?
>
> ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post
>   their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android
>   applications developers to help them get data from their applications
>   when they crash or behave erroneously.